# What are diplomas, postgraduate courses, specialization, training courses?

Tags: cv, job, faculty-application

I am going to apply for some faculty positions. In the application form they need some information in the category titled: `postgraduate courses, specialization and training courses and diploma`. I have already attended several summer schools, workshops and also took several online courses (MOOC) as well as knowledge booster courses. Can these events be considered as one of the elements of mentioned category? Need to say, there exists another category for degrees obtained such as Master and Doctoral.

Comment: They surely can be considered for that, yes. Don't ask me which is a postgrad course and which a training one though. :)

Comment: @Dirk None of them are postgraduate courses and none of them are likely to be training courses, but that depends.

Comment: @user40491, what country is this for? It might help us to understand what the category means. In the UK, none of what you listed would really fit that category but if you aren't talking about the UK my UK response wouldn't help you.